# What does pack("B*", $s) do In Perl?

Tags: python, perl

I am migrating some perl code to python and cant seem to understand what

```
pack("B*", $s)
```

does in perl.

Is there an equivalent in Python?

Comment: See the [`struct`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html) library, it has a `pack()` function that's similar.

Comment: It's a bit string pack — see, e.g., [`perlpacktut`](https://metacpan.org/dist/perl/view/pod/perlpacktut.pod#Bit-Strings) or the [`perlfunc`](https://metacpan.org/release/XSAWYERX/perl-5.34.0/view/pod/perlfunc.pod#pack-TEMPLATE,LIST) entry.  Does that help?

Comment: I still dont understand what this function is doing, it will take input $s as "001000000011" and return 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`pack`](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/pack):

> `B` A bit string (descending bit order inside each byte)

It takes a bit string, and produces the corresponding bytes.

For example, `pack "B*", "0100000101000010"` is equivalent to `"\x41\x42"` and `chr(65).chr(66)`.

````
$ perl -Mv5.10 -e'say sprintf "%vX", pack "B*", "0100000101000010"'
41.42
```
````

Comment: A little confused...

01000010 to decimal is 66 and 01000001 is 65

Comment: ...and hex 42 and 41 respectively

Comment: But why do I get back 0 when the string is "001000000011"

Comment: For `001000000011`, (`00100000 0011[0000]`) you get bytes 0x20 and 0x30. Printed as ASCII, that's space and zero.

Comment: Thank you so much for the clear explanation - I got it now.. do you happen to know if there is a python library that does exactly this? Otherwise I will make a function from scratch